# Micro Frontend Sub Component Loading on runtime

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I'm working an we app based React with microfrontend architect.It's uses module federation.I have some a problem witch is try to load a part of a mfe.I dont want to load all mfe.But i cant figure out it.Try to load all mfe and show it on hidden then show just the part i want.but if i have any alternative i can try it. For exaple when i click on composer button it will show part of mfe4.
[image: mfe-composer-schema]

Want to show part of a mfe in my composer app.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.